# iOS 5 custom annotation not showing its title

Tags: objective-c, ios, annotations

I wrote this code to create a custom annotation image

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *google = @"googlePin";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[myClass class]])
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:google];
        if (!annotationView)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:google];
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
        }
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;

}
```

The image is appearing on the map; however when I click on it nothing happen, no title nor subtitle.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Please provide the code where you set the title and subtitle of the 'myClass' object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you override `viewForAnnotation`, you have to set `canShowCallout` to `YES` (the default on a new view you alloc/init is `NO`).

If you don't override that delegate method, the map view creates a default red pin with `canShowCallout` already set to `YES`.

**However, even with `canShowCallout` set to `YES`, the callout will still not appear if the annotation's `title` is `nil` or blank (empty string)**.

(But again, if the `title` is not `nil` and not blank, the callout won't show unless `canShowCallout` is `YES`.)

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:google];
if (!annotationView)
{
    annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:google];
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;  // <-- add this
}
else
{
    // unrelated but should handle view re-use...
    annotationView.annotation = annotation; 
}

return annotationView;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working now. Only one question. Why do I have to use else if I am already returning annotationView in case it is not empty. Cheers